# Sentiment Analysis PowerBI AI Insights Visualization

Tags: powerbi, data-science, data-analysis

I have a Data Set of online product-reviews (without any grades/stars/etc.). To this data-set I applied the integrated PowerBI AI-Insights Text Analytics Sentiment Analysis model and got a a sentiment score for each review. Next, I transformed the score into textual discrete values: POSITIVE, NEGATIV and NEUTRAL.

The dataset is artificially created by me, so I know the polarity of each comment. Now I want to compare the predicted value to the actual value. I've done this by adding a new column that compares the actual value with the predicted value and displays "PREDICTED" if the correct value was predicted and "NOT PREDICTED" if the prediction was false (it doesn't matter if it is positive, negative or neutral). My goal is to calculate some model metrics so I can evaluate the capabilities of this PowerBI integrated model and to visualize the results. How can I do this? Is "accuracy" the first thing that I have to start with? If yes then how can I calculate and visualize a result like the "accuracy".

Thank you for all your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, take accuracy in first consideration. If you find 70 or 80 percent above results are accurate, you can easily rely on the PowerBI AI-Insights Text Analytics Sentiment Analysis. You can then create your visuals for Sentiment data. But if there is 50-50 occurrence of predicted and not predicted result, you may go for 3rd party Sentiment analysis service like - Google, Alchemy.